# python script doesn’t pick up environment variable that is set in crontab

Tags: python, shell, cron, environment-variables

When i run my python script from terminal i get error due to missing env variable. i can fix by this using `export` and setting it. But there are other python scripts that are running fine as cron jobs that require this as well. And i see this env variable being set in cron tab. So my question is if env variable set in cron is available for scripts run by user/root from cli? Running `env` command as root doesn’t show this variable.

Comment: Please show a minimal script and a minimal crontab along with the outputs when run both ways and say what OS you are running. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are private to each process, not global. When a new process is started it inherits its initial environment from its parent. Your terminal shell isn't started by cron so it doesn't inherit the env vars you've set in your crontab.

Your OS may provide a standard mechanism for setting env vars for all processes (e.g., your terminal which then starts your CLI shell). What I prefer to do is create a file named *~/.environ* that I then `source` in my *~/.bashrc* and cron jobs.

Comment: In my case it turned out that when I switched my user from root to the other one that was being used, I was able to access the env variable. So can cron set it for one user and that user can start terminal where env variable can be accessed ?